# Safer Way to Detect a SelectBox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I was asked to refresh a page (and it's data) based on the user's selection of an option in a select box.

I know that using the onChange event is the standard way to detect that a user changed their selection in a selectbox and I've done this a lot:

```
$("#provider").change(function(){

    var selectedprovider = $('#provider').val();

     //... Do something

});
```

I've also seen cases where certain browsers (IE) fire change events when a mouse wheel or arrow keys are being used to interact with the selectbox, not the actual event of changing an option selection.

Is there a better way to deal with this kind of scenario? For example checking to see if the array index of the selected option has changed? Not sure that there is an event for that specifically.

I am thinking it might be best to simply add a submit button next to the select box and stop trying to rely on the onChange event for select boxes.

How are you all handling this scenario?

Comment: _I've also seen cases where certain browsers (IE) fire change events when a mouse wheel or arrow keys are being used to interact with the selectbox_ __citation needed__

Comment: I do exactly this way and have never found any problem. But if you're not happy with that, you could always try `onblur` or `onfocusout`.

Comment: I really like knockout.js for this sort of thing, it isn't for everybody, and adding knockout just for a select box is a little much, hence the comment and not an answer, just something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to check to see if the value has actually changed at all since you registered your event. That would be one way to determine if the value is different or not.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/p9v7x/1/

```
$(function () {
    var lastVal = $('#target').val();
    $('#target').on('change', function () {
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.val() === lastVal) {
            // don't do anything if it's the same:
            console.log('same!');
        } else {
            // only do your action in this case:
            console.log(self.val());
        }
    });
});
```